# Mid - 2012 13" MacBook Pro screen conversion

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, screen

I have an extra Mid - 2012 13" MacBook Pro screen laying around, and was hoping to make it into an 
external display. I was also hoping to mount it into a rack drawer or tray. Anyone have any examples of projects similar that they've done?

Comment: I love the idea of up-cycling , but first things first..you need to make sure you have the right *driver* (not software).  You can usually find it by doing a search with the model/part number and word "driver" or find a supplier and contact them with the info.  I did a quick search and ran across this project:  http://dp2mbpr.rozsnyo.com/.  Without a driver, you'll be DOA in your projects.

Comment: You could also put it up on eBay because the amount of questions we get here about broken screens of that vintage would mean it would be a hot commodity...just sayin'